# Modulo $3$ calculations for a binomial-sum sequence

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics

Introduce the sequence (this is [A047781 on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A047781))
$$t_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k\binom{n+k}k$$
and denote the set $T(ij)=\{n\in\mathbb{N}: \text{the ternary digits of $n$ contain $i$ or $j$ only}\}$.

> **QUESTION.** Is this true modulo $3$?
> $$t_n\equiv_3\begin{cases} 1 \qquad \text{if $\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor\in T(01)$} \\
> 0 \qquad \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Comment: These kind of questions (for any prime, not only 3) can in principle be solved by a general result of Denef and Lipshitz, connecting finite automata with reduction of algebraic functions (or diagonals of rational functions) modulo p. A good reference with theory and examples is "Automatic congruences for diagonals of rational functions" by Rowland and Yassawi, Journal de Théorie des Nombres 
de Bordeaux 27 (2015), 245–288.

Comment: Is the question stated correctly? From the formula, $t_3 = \binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{5}{2} = 2 \times 4 + 1 \times 10 = 18 \equiv 0$ mod $3$. But $\lfloor 3/2 \rfloor = 1 \in T(01)$. Similarly $t_2 = \binom{1}{1}\binom{3}{1} = 1 \times 3 = 0$ mod $3$ and $\lfloor 2/1\rfloor = 1 \in T(01)$.

Comment: @MarkWildon: Oh, yes. The sum should start with $k=0$ not $k=1$. Thank you!

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky: I appreciate your reference. On the other hand, it might be an "overkill" to sort for those methods. So, I welcome more direct or elementary and specific proofs if possible.

Comment: If you want elementary, did you try a calculation with Lucas' theorem? At least to check that $t_n \equiv 1 \mod{3}$ if $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \in T(01)$? It would seem like a natural approach for this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is Yes.

The generating function for $t_n$ is
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} t_n x^n = \frac14\big(\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}-1\big).$$
Correspondingly,
$$\sum_{n\geq 0} t_n x^n \equiv \frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-1 \pmod{3}.$$
It follows that for $n>0$,
$$t_n \equiv \binom{-1/2}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\equiv (-1)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{2\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\pmod{3},$$
from where [Lucas' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a comment following Max Alekseyev's resolution. It has to do with his generating function for $t_n$ and working out directly on the Taylor's expansion (Binomial Theorem). Namely,
$$\frac14\left(\frac{1+x}{\sqrt{1-6x+x^2}}-1\right)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{h(n-1)+h(n)}4\,x^n$$
where
$$h(n)=\sum_{k=\lfloor\frac{n}2\rfloor}^n(-1)^{n+k}\binom{2k}k\binom{k}{n-k}3^{2k-n}2^{-n}.$$
To get to the conclusion we seek, let's just take $n\rightarrow 2n$ for instance. This leads to
\begin{align*}t_{2n}=\frac{h(2n-1)+h(2n)}4&\equiv_3h(2n-1)+h(2n) \\
&\equiv_3\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{2k}k\binom{k}{2n-1-k}3^{2k-2n+1}2^{-2n+1} \\
&+\sum_{k=n}^{2n}(-1)^k\binom{2k}k\binom{k}{2n-k}3^{2k-2n}2^{-2n} \\
&\equiv_3\sum_{k=n}^{2n}(-1)^k\binom{2k}k\binom{k}{2n-k}3^{2k-2n}2^{-2n} \\
&\equiv_3(-1)^n\binom{2n}n2^{-2n} \\
&\equiv_3(-1)^n\binom{2n}n.
\end{align*}

Comment: What is benefit of this explicit expansion?

Comment: I liked two things (pedagogically speaking): (1) I noticed what I did not expect, that is, $4t_n=h(n-1)+h(n)$; (2) I noticed the presence of the quantities $3^m$ vanishing mostly. Of course, no doubt about your approach is neater. By the way, how do you prove the generating function works for $t_n$? I saw it appeared on OEIS.

Comment: I copied g.f. from the OEIS, but I'm pretty sure it can be easily obtained by Lagrange inversion.